# vscode debugger is too complex

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZnzy.png)

In debugger, the string variable is not showing me concise value
I want to make debugger show me like
'test' = "aabb"

In someone else's debugger it`s showing exactly like that ('test' = "aabb") but mine not showing as like that..

please help me

Comment: `sting` is a complicated  little beastie and by default gdb shows *everything*. Assuming Visual Studio Code is sitting atop gdb for debugging, you're looking for what's called a "Pretty Printer".

Comment: How to not using gdb...? instead using what...?

Comment: Using GDB is ok, you need to enable "pretty printing" in it. Where did you install it from? Different distributions can behave slightly different in this regard.

Comment: I`m installed using MinGW installation Manager! I`m so sorry about to asking this but i don`t know how to enable pretty printing..

Comment: probably want to upvote this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3423

Comment: There are many MinGW distributions. From what link did you download yours?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

I was using this

Comment: With Marking 
mingw-developer-toolkit
mingw32-base
mingw32-gcc-g++
msys-base

Comment: The plain MinGW is bad for several reasons (no multithreading support, etc). https://www.msys2.org/ (or some other MinGW-w64 variant) is better. Last time I checked, in MSYS2 pretty-printing could be enabled with `python register_libstdcxx_printers(None)`. (In VSC you need to prepend `-exec ` to the command and run it in the debug console, I think).

Comment: If you have no loyalty to a tool chain or requirement to use a tool chain, consider using Visual Studio ([Community edition is "free"](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/free-developer-offers/)). Because Microsoft runs the ecosystem pretty much end-to-end, they can make sure all of the pieces fit. When you have a generalist program like VS Code the Pretty Printers can't easily keep up with all of the different the compilers and library revisions.

Comment: Please begin your comments with `@username`, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @user4581301 VSC doesn't provide pretty printers. They normally come with MinGW itself, but sometimes need to be manually enabled.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Doesn't surprise me. If you can't keep up, the only sane option is not try and go with something that ALWAYS works.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks I`m considering uninstall mingw and reinstalling this version https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download

is this will be fix the problem?

Comment: Its better to use msys2 to provide mingw. https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks but theme of vscode is soooo good

Comment: @drescherjm there is so many version of mingw...

Comment: msys2 provides a current version of mingw and also comes with a package manager that will make installing and updating many open source packages very easily. This is why I recommend it if you need to use mingw instead of msvc on windows.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay i will trust you instead of installing https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Comment: Joining in on the recommendation of msys2. The ecosystem of libraries it has will save you from a LOT of library compiling and wrangling when your programs get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you all who ever is helped me even my english is worse
(I`m not native speaker of english)

Comment: Here is a good set of msys2 installation instructions: [How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)